# Mysql View new field value

Tags: mysql, view

how can I create a new field depending on another field in the same view?

For example: I have table car, with the fields: car_name and car_type.

Depending which car_type it has (A, B, C or D) i wanted to create a new field in the view "price_class"

so if car_type = **A** then price_class is **> 100.000**. If it is
                 **B** then > **150.00**0
                 for **C** and **D** I want to set the same value

```
CREATE VIEW `car_price` AS
SELECT 
    `car`.`car_name` AS `name`,
    `car`.`car_type` AS `car_type`
FROM
    `car`
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what value do you want in price_class for types C & D?

Comment: for C and D it should always > 300.000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a `CASE` expression:

```
CREATE VIEW car_price AS
SELECT 
    car_name AS name,
    car_type AS car_type,
    CASE WHEN car_type = 'A' THEN '> 100.000'
         WHEN car_type = 'B' THEN '> 150.000'
         WHEN car_type IN ('C', 'D') THEN '> 300.000' END price_class
FROM car;
```

Comment: As you can probably guess from my comment to OPs post I was just typing the same thing...

Comment: @Nick I also have gotten blown out of the water a few times this morning.  Never pleasant.  Always annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Create another field based on condition using case when

```
CREATE VIEW `car_price` AS
SELECT 

    `car`.`car_name` AS `name`,
    `car`.`car_type` AS `car_type`,
case when `car`.`car_type`='A' then '> 100.000'
when `car`.`car_type`='B' then '> 150.000'
when `car`.`car_type` in ('C','D') then '> 300.000' end as price_class 
FROM
    `car`
```